# AS3 Apache Flex: click randomly not updating stage until mouse moves

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a SWF that displays a field of stars as a single BITMAP added to the Stage.  The image is dynamically generated through the Bitmap's BitmapData, to allow trackball interaction with the star field.  Planets and other buttons are also on the stage with hint Labels underneath.

All works as expected.  However, sometimes clicking a button, performs an operation, that does not show up until the mouse moves.  For example, clicking the button to toggle planet labels, will immediately update the stage with labels turning on and off.  But sometimes, the click does nothing, until the mouse is moved, or another click is made and then both clicks activate in series.

Same goes for a button that resets the star field to show either the Sun to Earth or Earth to Sun view.  Click the image (button) and the background star field updates immediately.  However, sometimes it does nothing until the mouse moves.  It seems like an interface timing issue beyond my control.

Anybody encounter this situation?  Working on MAC with Firefox, all latest updates.

Comment: It sounds like you're tapped into `mouseMove` instead of `click` or `mouseUp`.  Show your code, and we can help you further.

Comment: stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,flashResize);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,moveRespond);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickRespond);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,downRespond);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upRespond);

Comment: Works most of the time, but as stated above, very rare (1-n-100 clicks), APP is online at [link](http://OstrichEyes.com) and named Plodiac.  Maybe CLICK is fighting UP-DOWN.

Comment: That's a really cool app.  I like how the spherical distortion works.  That said, this is not enough code to identify what's going wrong.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and trying the app.  Sadly, I dont know what code to show.  The APP.swf is loaded by a WRAPPER.swf, thus APP holds all resources and the only thing Wrapper does is load, progress, contextmenu inherit.  App is loaded to stage by - var loadedSWF:Sprite=(e.target as LoaderInfo).content as Sprite;  - addChild(loadedSWF);  which seems to be the same as -  //addChild(e.currentTarget.content);  Other than that all events are caught for click, drag and resize.  Just sometimes miss a click, but the click IS in the queue.  Another click will send both.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the event code.

```
private function moveRespond(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var X:int=mouseX,Y:int=mouseY,R:int=Assets.Assets.radius/10; if(R<15){R=15}
    if( moveActive ) {
        Assets.Assets.STUFF.view.rotateMatrix(PT.x,PT.y,X,Y);
        FIELD.update(w,h);
        }
    else {
        Assets.Assets.STUFF.line.hover(X,Y,R);
        var btn:Vector.<Button>=Assets.Assets.BTN_list;
        var i:int,I:int=btn.length;
        for( i=0; i<I; i++ ) {
            btn[i].label.visible=btn[i].hover(X,Y);
        }   }
    DP.x=PT.x-X; PT.x=X;
    DP.y=PT.y-Y; PT.y=Y;
    }
private function upRespond(e:MouseEvent):void { moveActive=false }
private function downRespond(e:MouseEvent):void { moveActive=true;
    var X:int=mouseX,Y:int=mouseY;
    PT.x=X; PT.y=Y;
    }
private function clickRespond(e:MouseEvent):void {
...
//lots of button management, similar to above
//FIELD.update(w,h); and new zodiac sign fetch...
//but if there was a soft error in here,
//then the click at the end would get skipped,
//and it doesnt.
...
    if( click ) { Assets.Assets.soundClick(X); }
    }
```

Because of the randomness of the error, I'm assuming a memory thrashing somewhere in my code that is interrupting the next event, but kinda hoping its a communications issue because the missed-click is Event-queued.  It just doesnt get sent to my App until either a move or another click.  The App.swf can be run without the wrapper (preloader basically), and it has the same randomness.  Even though it is very rare, it is still very annoying.

There is also a ConstantUpdate timer:

```
public function constantUpdate(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    Mouse.hide(); Mouse.show();
    dateMessage();
    if( !Assets.Assets.BTN_help.glowing && Math.random()<0.05 ) { Assets.Assets.BTN_help.glow(); }
    if( !Assets.Assets.BTN_logo.glowing && Math.random()<0.01 ) { Assets.Assets.BTN_logo.glow(); }
    if( !Assets.Assets.BTN_next.glowing && Math.random()<0.05 ) { Assets.Assets.BTN_next.glow(); }
    Assets.Assets.BTN_help.update();
    Assets.Assets.BTN_logo.update();
    Assets.Assets.BTN_next.update();
    Assets.Assets.BTN_star.update();
    Assets.Assets.BTN_note.update();
    Assets.Assets.BTN_moon.update();
    }
```

Just more button management.  The Mouse hide/show pings the Mouse after the contextMenu deactivates.  Otherwise, the mouse turned into an arrow over the contextMenu and would stay that way until mouse left the window and returned.  Still have some mouse hick-ups on startup though - not setting my cursor after App.swf loaded.  Have no idea if that is related to the clicking issue, but here's that code:

```
var cursor:MouseCursorData=new MouseCursorData();
    cursor.hotSpot=new Point(
        Assets.Assets.BTN_sun.icon.width/2,
        Assets.Assets.BTN_sun.icon.height/2);
    var pointer:Vector.<BitmapData>=new <BitmapData>[Assets.Assets.BTN_sun.icon.bitmapData];
    cursor.data=pointer;
    Mouse.registerCursor("myCursor",cursor);
    Mouse.cursor="myCursor";
```

I dont keep a local handle to the cursor object.

Comment: It appears you're not handling mouse events directly, but rather setting values, and checking on them later at intervals inside `constantUpdate()`, correct?  Also, `btn[i].label.visible = btn[i].hover(X,Y);` is a curious line; `hover()` would appear to be returning a Boolean value based on the X/Y values (perhaps it's returning integers)?  The code you've provided is helpful, but I'm afraid I'm still as mystified as you are as to these odd button updates.  You haven't indicated what events you've registered for, and what listeners they call, but I suspect it is this indirect event approach.

Comment: If I were you, I'd set a break-point inside this function that's being called which "resets the star field to show the Sun to Earth".  When the function fails to get called immediately (and only after you mouseMove), you'll see the Call Stack and why the function was called when it did.  Perhaps the events are being called correctly, but the onscreen update didn't draw?

Comment: All good comments but dead ends.  The visible=hover is just ugly code.  I'm testing this on MAC using Firefox, but on MAC, Safari is the gatekeeper, so Firefox is still driven through Safari.  To add to the confusion, I ran the app on both at the same time.  Could not get the missed-click on Safari, but now the cursor in Firefox flickered like crazy due to the Mouse hide/show pings - running the app in Safari effected the app's cursor in Firefox!  I'm going the log this issue with Mozilla.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The MouseUP event seems redundant since the Click event is sent on an UP action.  However, I was not sure if this would be the same on all platforms.  Maybe the Click event is sent on a mouse down action in a different browser, and I want to make sure the drag action is concluded properly, so added the mouse up catch.  However, after a missed-click, the Mouse Down action produced a Click Event, followed by another Click event on the mouse up - purposely clicking slow to see that.  Will a Click Event always be generated on a Mouse Up action?  Maybe these events are clobbering each other.

Comment: The `click` event exists to provide a simple way of only getting an event when both the mouseDown & mouseUp occur over the same InteractiveObject  (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:click). So, yes: it always occurs with a mouseUp (with conditions) on all platforms.  However, it is interesting that you mention you're working with drag actions; perhaps the `click` event is being fire because `mouseUp -> mouseDown` is conditionally equivalent to `mouseDown -> mouseUp`?  If so, it may explain the phantom clicks.

Comment: Then again, it may be as simple as multiple listeners in the same button.  If you have a square `Sprite` with a child `TextField` and weren't careful about what's firing events, both could generate events, or the mouseDown could be read on the `TextField` and the `mouseUp` on the `Sprite` with a consecutive click resolve the conditions for both.  It's a shot in the dark, but I thought worth considering.